# How can I add phone number for corresponding author in elsarticle style

Tags: titles, document-classes, elsarticle, front-matter

Following the Elsarticle template, they provide the way to add corresponding author as below.

```
%% Title, authors and addresses

%% use the tnoteref command within \title for footnotes;
%% use the tnotetext command for theassociated footnote;
%% use the fnref command within \author or \address for footnotes;
%% use the fntext command for theassociated footnote;
%% use the corref command within \author for corresponding author footnotes;
%% use the cortext command for theassociated footnote;
%% use the ead command for the email address,
%% and the form \ead[url] for the home page:
%% \title{Title\tnoteref{label1}}
%% \tnotetext[label1]{}
%% \author{Name\corref{cor1}\fnref{label2}}
%% \ead{email address}
%% \ead[url]{home page}
%% \fntext[label2]{}
%% \cortext[cor1]{}
%% \address{Address\fnref{label3}}
%% \fntext[label3]{}
```

I want to used above rule to add my detail as

```
           Author 1 name^a, Author 2 name^a, Corresponding name^{a,*}
      a Address here...
      * Corrpesonding author. Tel. ... Email...
```

I tried with

```
\author[a]{Author 1 name}
\author[a]{Author 2 name}
\author[a]{Corresponding name\corref{cor1}}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
 \ead {email@}
\address[a]{Address here}
```

But it cannot add phone for corresponding author. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with `\corref{label}` within `\author` command, this will generate the corresponding output of `\cortext[label]`.  So the respective `\author` may be coded as:

```
\author[a]{ Author c name\corref{cor1}}
```

Comment: Thanks. How to add phone number of  corresponding author?

Comment: Can be given in \cortext, for example:

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author. Tel.: +00 0 00 000 0000; fax: +00 ...}